# Matching column to substring of different column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:
`df_student_modules_nofail`

```
data = {
    'CCode': ['MG5002', 'MG5003', 'MG5005', 'MG5028', 'MG5029', 'MG5030', 'MG5033', 'MG6032', 'MG6037', 'MG6038',
              'MG6103', 'MG6136', 'MG6051', 'MG7101', 'MG7121', 'DCFE700', 'MG6033', 'MG7026', 'MG7101B', 'MG7028'],
    'PassFail': ['PASS'] * 20,
    'CStat': ['Co', 'Co', 'Co', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'Co', 'C', 'E', 'A-MG7101A', 'Co', 'O', 'C', 'NM', 'Co', 'E']
}

df_student_modules_nofail = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and `dffc`

```
data = {
    'CCode': ['MG5004', 'MG7101A', 'MG5034'],
    'PassFail': ['', '', ''],
    'CStat': ['Co', 'Co', 'A-MG5033']
}

dffc = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to set the value of `dffc.PassFail` to 'Duplicate' if

1. `df_student_modules_nofail.CCode` is a substring in `dffc.CStat`
2. `dffc.CCode` is a substring in `df_student_modules_nofail.CStat`

The first of these I have managed (with the help of ChatGPT 3.5 as I really struggle with this kind of search) using:

```
mask = dffc['CStat'].str.contains('|'.join(df_student_modules_nofail['CCode']))
dffc.loc[mask, 'PassFail'] = 'Duplicate'
```

However I can't figure out the second, and ChatGPT can't either. I thought it would be this:

```
mask = df_student_modules_nofail['CStat'].str.contains('|'.join(dffc['CCode']))
dffc.loc[mask, 'PassFail'] = 'Duplicate'
```

But I get

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

ChatGPT said I needed to use regex to construct a pattern for the mask, but it's solution had the same error. It also suggested a for loop which didn't work either and seemed a bad/slow idea in any case.
Please can you help with this?

Edit as requested in comments: The desired output would be:

```
data = {
    'CCode': ['MG5004', 'MG7101A', 'MG5034'],
    'PassFail': ['', 'Duplicate', 'Duplicate'],
    'CStat': ['Co', 'Co', 'A-MG5033']
}

dffc = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

MG5034/PassFail would be changed because of the first test (this I've managed).
MG7101A/PassFail would be changed because of the second test.

Comment: provide desire output of your example in text table or code

Comment: I don't get a `TypeError` when I run the code, but it also doesn't make any changes. Are you sure you copy-pasted the right things?

Comment: FWIW, look at the second `mask`. The indexes don't correspond with `dffc` since it's based on `df_student_modules_nofail`. That's why it didn't do anything when I tried it.

Comment: Why not just extract the CCode from CStats that start with `'A-'`? Wouldn't that be way easier?

Comment: @wjandrea, I can't just extract the CCode from CStats as in a small number of cases a course is an alternative to multiple other courses, so It's CStat looks like 'A-MG5001,MG5002,MG5003' This is why I need to substring match (I think, unless there is an alternative)

Comment: @ic198 Looks like you can extract `r'A-(.*)'` then just split the result on comma